# Overwrite a plugin's template file

Tags: magento2, template

I have the plugin in a directory

```
app/code/Amasty/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html
```

that I would like to style (unfortunately, it can't be done only with CSS).

***Is it possible to overwrite a plugin's template?***

As it is not a good idea to fiddle with the files in plugin's folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an HTML template:

```
app/code/Amasty/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html
```

I can give you some suggestions:

1) Override it by using require js:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Amasty_Checkout/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html': 
              'Vendor_Module/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html'
        }
  }
};
```

2) If having a custom theme, copy to your theme

For example:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/web/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html
```

3) This way is always useful for Checkout page: change template or js component via XML. If you want to use this way, you should learn more about the js component. 
Read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

Search through the module or project: `onepage/shipping/methods`, you can see this file in XML or Js file.

a) Change JS component:

[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="shipping_policy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/[your]/[js]/[component]</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In this way, you can add custom Js function to the template. BUT, for the JS component, one of the difficult parts of Magento 2, should start learning here:

https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_introducing_ui_components/

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html

b) Change template via XML: if simply want to change the html template, choose this way

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="shipping_policy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/[your]/[template]</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can combine two ways together:

```
......
<item name="shipping_policy" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/[your]/[js]/[component]</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/[your]/[template]</item>
    </item>
</item>
......
```

Comment: Thank you Khoa, you saved my day! I can confirm that I have tried the second variant and it is work.